# OpenCV: Crop an image based on certain condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, python-imaging-library

I need to crop the image when ever there's a blank space detected.
[image: input image]

and the expected output is the individual cropped images of the input data like below after blank space is detected between two text in an image.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

Any idea would be appreciated!

Comment: Threshold on the green or the background color using cv2.inRange(). Invert as needed so that the letters are white. Use a horizontal morphology close such that the letters space is closed, but not so large that the space between words is filled. Then get contours and get the bounding boxes. Then use the bounding boxes to crop the original image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I suggest to do that in Python/Opencv from my comment above.

"Threshold on the green using cv2.inRange(). Use a horizontal morphology close such that the letters space is closed, but not so large that the space between words is filled. Then get contours and get the bounding boxes. Then use the bounding boxes to crop the original image."

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the image
img = cv2.imread('StandOutFrom.png')

# threshold on green
lower=(30,30,0)
upper=(110,110,60)
thresh = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

# apply horizontal close morphology
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (15,3))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# get external contours
contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

# get bounding boxes and save to disk
i = 1
result = img.copy()
for cntr in contours:
    # get bounding boxes
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
    cv2.rectangle(result, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    print(i,x,y,w,h)
    crop = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imwrite("StandOutFrom_crop_{0}.png".format(i), crop)
    i = i + 1

# save result
cv2.imwrite('StandOutFrom_thresh.png', thresh )
cv2.imwrite('StandOutFrom_morph.png', morph )
cv2.imwrite('StandOutFrom_bounding_boxes.png', result )

# show results
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('morph', morph)
cv2.imshow('boundingboxes', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Threshold Image:

[image]

Morphology Close Image:

[image]

Bounding Box Image:

[image]

Result Images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Get the contours of the detected Word's and Iterate through the points and crop them, Something like this

```
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0,255,0), 4)
    ROI = original[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```

The ROI will be the word part of image extracted based on Contour detected

Comment: this is only half the solution. You are missing an approach to detect the contours of the words

Comment: your edit didn't change the fact that `Get the contours of the detected Word` is still a non-trivial part of the complete solution

Comment: He is looking for a idea of the solution. I have given him a hint or something he can use to find a clue for the solution he needs. And writing the complete code or solution for others is not anyone's job, all we can do is help along the way, If they have doubts they can comment and I believe the amount of information I have shared is enough for a person to figure out the solution on their own.